# Windows Server own licence

Tags: windows

I want to use my own licences in Google Cloud Platform the question is...

If I have Windows Server licences, Could I Start a new instance of Windows Server in GCP using my own licences?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/) states:

> You cannot migrate your existing Windows Server licenses to Compute Engine, but you can [bring your existing Microsoft Application Licenses](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/ms-licensing) to your Windows Server instances to run specific applications. However, you must continue to manage those licenses yourself.

Which requires Volume Licensing and Software Assurance for those specific applications. But you can't use your own licenses for Windows Server itself.